# ruby with wildcard rspec command not working on windows machines

Tags: ruby, windows, rspec

I have made a ruby command line "frontend" that sets different environment variables according to user input, a sort of "ncurses" frontend but only in ruby, I know there is Rake and such tools, but we made it this way because we need the variables that can be set at runtime according to need, and the frontend also can send the running results via email to my team.

This works very well in linux machines but in windows its not working.

I track down the problem to the rspec command that has a wildcard in the filename, this works perfectly in linux, but if i run the commands manually in windows, it didn't do anything. If i run the rspec command with one file it works fine, but not with wildcards.

I tried a couple of google searches, tried this workarounds i found, but  without success:

(this snippet is inside a ruby file I run with "ruby FILE.rb")

```
system("rspec #{spec\2.2\web_pc_*} -e '#{ARGV[1]}' -o log.txt")
system("rspec #{spec\2.2\web_pc_/*} -e '#{ARGV[1]}' -o log.txt")
system("rspec #{spec\2.2\web_pc_'*'} -e '#{ARGV[1]}' -o log.txt")
system("rspec #{spec\2.2\web_pc_"*"} -e '#{ARGV[1]}' -o log.txt")
system("rspec #{spec\2.2\'web_pc_*'} -e '#{ARGV[1]}' -o log.txt")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I had found, is to make a Rakefile and run the Rake command. This way all the files execute no matter what OS i'm running them.

Rakefile:

```
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new(:all) do |t|
  t.libs << "tests"
  t.test_files = FileList['tests/test_*.rb']
  t.verbose = true
end

task default: :all
```